# How can I get python to show me the differance between 2 images and display them with Circles around

Tags: python, opencv

So I have started a program that takes two images, one that's the model image and the other that's an image with a change I want it to detect the differences and show me with circling the differences. I have come to an issue with finding the difference coordinates as my circle keeps ending up in the middle of the image.

This is the code I have:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

#Ideal Image and The main Image
img2= cv.imread("ideal.jpg")
img1 = cv.imread("Actual.jpg")


#Verifys if there is or isnt a differance in the Image for the If statement
diff = cv.subtract(img2, img1)
results = not np.any(diff)

#Tells the User if there is a Differance within the 2 images with the model image and the image given
if results is True:
    print("The Images are the same!")

else:
    print("The images are differant")


#This is to make the image show the differance to circle
img_1=Image.open("Actual.jpg")
img_2=Image.open("ideal.jpg")
diff=ImageChops.difference(img_1,img_2)
diff.save("Differance.jpg")

#Reads the image Just saved
Differance = cv.imread("Differance.jpg", 0)

#Resize the Image to make it smaller

img1s = cv.resize(img1, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
Differance = cv.resize(Differance, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)    

# Find anything not black, i.e. The differance
nz = cv.findNonZero(Differance)

# Find top, bottom, left and right edge of the Differance
a = nz[:,0,0].min()
b = nz[:,0,0].max()
c = nz[:,0,1].min()
d = nz[:,0,1].max()

# Average top and bottom edges, left and right edges, to give centre
c0 = (a+b)/2
c1 = (c+d)/2

#The Center Coords
c3 = (int(c0),int(c1))

#Values for the below code so it doesnt look messy
radius = 50
color = (0, 0, 255)
thickness = 2

#This Places a Circle around the center of the differance
Finished = cv.circle(img1s, c3, radius, color, thickness)

#Saves the Final Image with the circle around it
cv.imwrite("Final.jpg", Finished)
```

And the Images attached [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6xTM.jpg)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZi5p.jpg)

This code currently takes both images and blacks out the background leaving only the difference within the image then the program is meant to take the location of the difference and place a circle around the center of the main image that is the one with the difference on it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please edit your question with what your current code does, and how that differs from the expected result.

Comment: I don't understand why you save `Differance` and read it again - it is waste of time.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables. Maybe you calculate position in wrong way. OR maybe you use wrong values. Maybe some function gives different result then you expect. Maybe `.min()` doesn't give minimal coordinates but minimal value. maybe it needs something like `minarg()` or similar.

Comment: if you display images - `diff`, `Differance` - then you should see possible problem: you keep images as JPG so some pixels are different in all area. `JPG` changes pixels to create better compression. You should keep image as `PNG` or `TIFF` which doesn't change pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is `JPG` format which changes pixels to better compress image - and this creates differences in all area. If you display `diff` or `difference` then you should see many gray pixels

I hope you see pixels below ball

[image]

If you use `PNG` for original image (without ball) and later use this image to create image with ball and also save in `PNG` then code will works correctly.

---

My version without `PIL`.

Press any key to close window with image.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# load images
img1 = cv.imread("img1.png")
img2 = cv.imread("img2.png")

# calculate difference
diff = cv.subtract(img1, img2)  # other order `(img2, img1)` gives worse result

# saves difference
cv.imwrite("difference.png", diff)

# show difference - press any key to close
cv.imshow('diff', diff)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyWindow('diff')

if not np.any(diff):
    print("The images are the same!")
else:
    print("The images are differant")

# resize images to make them smaller
#img1_resized = cv.resize(img1, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
#diff_resized = cv.resize(diff, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)    
img1_resized = img1
diff_resized = diff

# convert to grayscale (without saving and loading again)
diff_resized = cv.cvtColor(diff_resized, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# find anything not black in differance
non_zero = cv.findNonZero(diff_resized)
#print(non_zero)

# find top, bottom, left and right edge of the differance
x_min = non_zero[:,0,0].min()
x_max = non_zero[:,0,0].max()
y_min = non_zero[:,0,1].min()
y_max = non_zero[:,0,1].max()
print('x:', x_min, x_max)
print('y:', y_min, y_max)

sizes = [x_max-x_min+1, y_max-y_min+1]
print('width :', sizes[0])
print('height:', sizes[1])

# center 
center_x = (x_min + x_max) // 2
center_y = (y_min + y_max) // 2
center = (center_x, center_y)
print('center:', center)

# radius 
radius = max(sizes) // 2
print('radius:', radius)

color = (0, 0, 255)
thickness = 2

# draw circle around the center of the differance
finished = cv.circle(img1_resized, center, radius, color, thickness)

# saves final image with circle
#cv.imwrite("final.png", finished)

# show final image - press any key to close
cv.imshow('finished', finished)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyWindow('finished')
```

---

`img1.png`

[image]

`img2.png`

[image]

`difference.png`

[image]

`final.png`

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

If you work with `JPG` then you can try to reduce noises

```
diff = cv.subtract(img1, img2)

diff_gray = cv.cvtColor(diff, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

diff_gray[diff_gray < 50] = 0
```

For different images you may need different values instead of `50`.

You may also try [thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

```
(_, diff_gray) = cv.threshold(diff_gray, 50, 0, cv.THRESH_TOZERO)
```

It may need also other functions like `blur()`, `erode()`, `dilate()`,

Answer (score 0):

do not need PIL

1. take Differance image
2. threshold it
3. use findcontour to find regions
4. if contours finded then draw it

```
for cnt in contours:
    out_image = cv2.drawContours(out_image, [cnt], 0, (255,0,0), -1)
    (x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
    center = (int(x),int(y))
    radius = int(radius)
    out_image = cv2.circle(out_image,center,radius,(0,255,0),2)
```